# Find all vertices connected to a vertice using igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a function to find the number of vertices connected to a vertex in a graph using R's igraph library? The vertices don't need to be joined by a direct edge, they can have longer path lengths between them-- they just need to be "connected".

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any example data so I will use something you can generate from igraph. The function `components` in igraph computes the connected components and their sizes. The example below gets the size of the component that contains node number 13 (including node 13 itself).

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(2017)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 1/20)
Comp = clusters(g)
Comp$csize[Comp$membership[13]]
[1] 7
```